# Safari for iPad: How to hide the Autofill Bar above the keyboard?

Tags: ipad, ios, keyboard, mobile-safari, autofill

I'm coding an iPad application that uses a UIWebView which contains an <input> tag. It doesn't make sense in the context of the app to use AutoFill, but when editing the field, a bar appears above the keyboard with "AutoFill" and "Previous / Next".

Is there a way to tag/style the <input> so that this bar does not appear? Adding autocomplete="off" doesn't do it. Barring that, is there a way to bypass Safari's keyboard, and call out to iOS APIs to handle the text input instead? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, this is a feature of Mobile Safari which is under the control of the end user, and cannot be enabled/disabled by your application.